# Access information about temp tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

In SQL Server Management Studio, I have a bunch of temporary tables, they look like they were created by the system:

[image]

Can I drop them? How can I get more information about them? For example, what procedures are creating these? I'd like to fix what is causing this.

Thanks!

Comment: No worries, these will auto delete when procedure call ends.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but these tables were created several hours ago.  Does that mean a procedure has crashed?  None of the procedures should really run more than a minute or two.

Comment: Depending on how they're created, it might require that the connections they were created on get disconnected.